# Inspect an app from ipad using Safari Web Inspector

Tags: ios, safari, ibm-mobilefirst, web-inspector

I want to use Safari web inspector in order to inspect an ipad application which I developed using eclipse and worklight.

Obviously when I connect my ipad with the mac, i go to safari--->develop--->ipad--->no inspectable applications.

When I open the app in safari (as a web page) it works but this is not what I want. I just need to inspect directly the app. Is this possible?

I have enabled web inspector ON in my device safari device settings, private browsing is off and I have clear all the data history and the cookies.

I am using:

Mac

Yosemite 10.10.2
safari 8.0.3

Ipad air2

iOS 8.1.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that the application you've installed on the device was built to the device from Xcode, and is not from a production build - in that case it will not be available in the Safari Inspector.